# update statement in oracle with join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have made this sql and I need to update table with given result

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.t1_val3, t1.t1_val4
                DECODE (b_val,
                        'A', 'Its A',
                        'B', 'Its B',
                        'C', 'Its C',
                        NULL
                       ) decode_val,

           FROM t1, t2, t3
          WHERE t1.t1_val = t2.t2_val
            AND t2.t2_val = t3.t3_val
            AND t3.t3_val2 <> 'PSA'
            AND t3.t3_val2 = 'Y'
```

Now using this query I need to update t1 table.

something like this,

```
update t1 
set
t1.val5=decode_val
where t1.t1_val3= value returned from above query(first column t1_val3) 
and t1.t1_val4= value returned from above query(2nd column t1_val4)
```

DB - 10g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are on 10g, the `MATCHED` and `NOT MATCHED` clauses are now **`optional`**.

```
MERGE INTO t1 a
USING (SELECT DISTINCT t1.t1_val3, t1.t1_val4
                DECODE (b_val,
                        'A', 'Its A',
                        'B', 'Its B',
                        'C', 'Its C',
                        NULL
                       ) decode_val,

           FROM t1, t2, t3
          WHERE t1.t1_val = t2.t2_val
            AND t2.t2_val = t3.t3_val
            AND t3.t3_val2 <> 'PSA'
            AND t3.t3_val2 = 'Y') b
ON(a.t1_val3 = b.t1_val_3 and a.t1_val4 = b.t1_val4)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET a.t1.val5 = b.decode_val
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
update t1 
set
t1.val5 =DECODE (b_val,
                    'A', 'Its A',
                    'B', 'Its B',
                    'C', 'Its C',
                    NULL
                   ) 

       FROM t1, t2, t3
      WHERE t1.t1_val = t2.t2_val
        AND t2.t2_val = t3.t3_val
        AND t3.t3_val2 <> 'PSA'
        AND t3.t3_val2 = 'Y'
```

Comment: Please verify your post before submitting,  always use code tags and check if the tags are properly applied.

Comment: im new here.sorry :)

Comment: No problem. I have edited your answer.

Comment: mark it as Answer ,this may help someone

Comment: I have voted up for your answer and marked lalit's solution as answer, he provided solution earlier. Thanks :)